# Hartogs' Theorem

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

> Show that the well-ordering theorem is equivalent to:
>   For any two sets $X$ and $Y$ there is an injection of $X$ to $Y$ or $Y$ to $X$.

I have only some ideas for the "$\Leftarrow$" direction:
If we have $f:X\to Y$ is injective, then follows ((5.2) in Jech) that $|X|\geq |Y|$.
(By choosing $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ for each $y\in Y$.)
Since we can choose $X$ and $Y$ arbitrarily, I thought we can then compare all elements in $X$ and also find a least element. But I don't really know how to get there formally.

For the other direction I have no idea yet.

I'd be very happy for any hint how to approach this proof!

Comment: It's Hartogs', not Hartog's, because it's named after [Friedrich Hartogs](http://enwp.org/Friedrich_Hartogs).

Comment: I think you've got (5.2) in Jech incorrect. To me it reads: if $f$ maps $A$ onto $B$ then $| B | \leq | A |$.  (And your question doesn't have much to do with surjective functions.)  (The implication "if $f$ is a one-to-one function from $A$ into $B$ then $|A| \leq |B|$" is a definition, however.)

Comment: Oh, thanks for the correction!

Comment: For the $\Rightarrow$ direction you may want to find ordinals $\alpha,\beta$ such that you have bijections $X\rightarrow\alpha$ and $Y\rightarrow\beta$ and find an injection from $\alpha$ into $\beta$ or in the other direction.


For the other direction, let $X$ be a set you want to wellorder and take $\alpha$ be the ordinal constructed in the proof of Hartogs' Theorem. Now use your assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For a set $X$ show that there exists a least ordinal $\kappa$ such that $\kappa\nleq|X|$. In order to show its existence you will need to show it is the range of a function whose domain is $\mathcal{P(P(}X))$ (and use replacement).

Now we have that $\kappa\nleq|X|$ so $|X|<\kappa$. Conclude Zermelo's theorem.